# How to use a condition when writing to a .txt file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create myself a powershell script that has mainly two tasks - one after the other.

Initial assumptions: it runs where it performs the following tasks.

1. Trace all the files, those that are folders - make a zip of them, then after making the archive, delete them. Objective accomplished.
2. Write to the file the names of all files in the folder (after completing point 1) but check if the given file has the extension of *.zip
   a) if it has extension of *.zip then it should be saved in .txt file like "uresoruce = foo/file.zip"
   b) if it doesn't have extension *.zip then it should be saved to a .txt file like this "resoruce = foo/file2.jar"
   c) since the script is started from the place where all the files are, it will probably also be saved to a file, I would like to avoid this

Suppose we have some files in a folder after compiling, and we don't have any folder inside. The .txt file should look like the following:

> uresource = plugins/Liula_1.0.0.0.zip

> uresource = plugins/Liborts_3.7.1.0.zip

> uresource = plugins/Liwer_1.2.0.0.zip

> resource = plugins/o0.I20100512-1500.jar

> resource = plugins/or.v20100505-1235.jar

The script I managed to write so far:

```
## set current path
$path = (Resolve-Path .\).Path

## dirs in a path
$source = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "" -Directory
$files = Get-ChildItem $path

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

Foreach ($s in $source) {

  $destination = Join-path -path $path -ChildPath "$($s.name).zip"

  [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $destination)
  
  Remove-Item $s -Recurse
}

# This does not working!!! :/
Foreach ($f in $files) {
  $extn = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($f)
  if ($extn -eq ".zip" ) {
    $outfile = "uresource = plugins/" + $f.Name 
  }
  else {
    $outfile = "resource = plugins/" + $f.Name 
  } 
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting unexpected output? No output? Please remember only you can see your screen :)

Comment: Your last `foreach` loop is assigning values to the variable `$outfile` but then you're not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Santiago Squarzon rightly pointed out I did not do anything with this variable. I got a little confused because before I did it only for out-file I didn't use -append and in fact I got the last value in .txt. Now I made my first script in ph, it works like a dream ;)

```
## set current path
$path = (Resolve-Path .\).Path

## dirs in a path
$source = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "" -Directory
$files = Get-ChildItem $path

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

## create zip and delete other dirs
Foreach ($s in $source) {

  $destination = Join-path -path $path -ChildPath "$($s.name).zip"

  [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $destination)
  
  Remove-Item $s -Recurse
}

## output filename in .txt
$logFile = "$pwd\logfile.txt"
Foreach ($f in $files) {
    $extn = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($f)
    if ($extn -eq ".zip" ) {$outfile = "uresource = plugins/$f"}
    else {$outfile = "resource = plugins/$f"}
    $outfile | Out-File -Append $logFile
}
```